# How does $2^{12} \times 3^{12} \times 4^6 \times 8^4 \times 9^6 \times 27^4$ become $6^{36}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is for a math team practice packet and I don't understand how to do this without a calculator (they're not allowed on this one):

$$2^{12} \times 3^{12} \times 4^6 \times 8^4 \times 9^6 \times 27^4$$

It simplifies into $6^{36}$ in order to solve the rest of the problem and I understand how to do the rest, but I just don't understand how to simplify it this far and the answer sheet does say how to.

Comment: Just write each term as $2^a$ or $3^b$ for suitable exponents.  You can do it in your head.

Comment: @lulu How would that help convert it to 6 as a base then once I have 2^a and 3^b

Comment: You can't in general. But if you end up with $a=b$, you know $2^a \times 3^a = 6^a$. And this problem happens to work out that way.

Comment: It will take 2 steps. First do what lulu says, and then use $a^n b^n = (ab)^n$. Note that lulu's step can always be done, but the second step is just a "lucky accident" that applies in this case. In fact, me, if I was answering it, I would leave the $2$ and $3$ separate, but I guess your answer sheet wants you to combine them.

Comment: I agree with the comments.  I'd have left the answer as $2^{36}\times 3^{36}$.  Factoring is hard, so if the problem gives you something in factored form, keep it that way.  Of course, combining the terms is very easy in this case.

Comment: @lulu: Well, that depends on the numbers you're factoring.  In this particular case, where everything's a small power or 2 or 3, it's easy.  Factoring a number like 991074367 is hard without a computer.  And the lack of a known fast general algorithm for factoring hundreds-of-digits numbers is the whole basis of the RSA cryptosystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break all the numbers down into their prime factors, then recombine.

$2^{12} \times 3^{12} \times 4^6 \times 8^4 \times 9^6 \times 27^4$

= $2^{12} \times 3^{12} \times (2^2)^6 \times (2^3)^4 \times (3^2)^6 \times (3^3)^4$

= $2^{12 + 2 \times 6+ 3 \times 4} \times 3^{12 + 2 \times 6 + 3 \times 4}$

= $2^{36} \times 3^{36}$

= $(2 \times 3)^{36}$

= $6^{36}$